# Unable to use localhost with Docker Container

Tags: docker

I have tried other answers on stackoverflow and github, but none of them are working. 
When I run the container
[I get this as the output(Which is the standard "flask run" output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmkR8.png)

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev && pip3 install --upgrade pip 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 install Flask && pip3 install requests && pip3 install simplejson

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "flask", "run" ]
```

I have tried 0.0.0.0:5000 too but its not working.

Comment: Which machine are you working on? Also, can you share the result of running ```docker ps```

Comment: @VishakhaLall It's MacOS and here's the screenshot of docker ps : https://imgur.com/a/a22F0w2

Comment: You cannot access anything on port `5000` using hostname or IP address is that your problem. ?? You cannot access anything that is running on localhost inside docker

Comment: When you say "I get this as the output", what do you actually get?  Your script and `docker ps` probably write out text, not PNG files or links; include that text directly in the question (not a link and never a screenshot of a terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to know the IP address of the host.
 `boot2docker ip`

Now use this IPAddress along with the port number mapped to your host.

When you spawn a container that is running a process such as a web server,  you need to specify what ports to publish from the container to the host, for example

```
docker run -p 8888:8080 tomcat
```

this publishes port **8080** from the container to the host’s port **8888**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can expose a port through your Dockerfile or use --expose and
   then publish it with the -P flag. This will bind the exposed port to
   your Docker host on a random port (verified by running docker
   container ls).
2. You can expose a port through your Dockerfile or use --expose and
       then publish it with the -p 80:80 flag. This will bind the exposed
       port to your Docker host on port 80, and it expects the exposed port
       is 80 too (adjust as necessary with HOST:CONTAINER).
3. You can ignore exposing anything and just use -p 80:80 in which case
       this doubles as both exposing AND publishing the port.

Try running,

```
docker run -d --name <your_ctr_name>-p 5000:5000 <your_image_name>:latest
```

If you need to bind host,

```
docker run -d --name container_name -p 10.x.x.100:5000:5000 image_name:latest
```

If you want to expose the docker using network host,

```
docker run -d  --network host --name container_name image_name:latest
```

Comment: --network host does not work with OSX to access localhost.

Comment: Ohh okay, I have less experience with OSX, can this work `-p 10.x.x.100:5000:5000 `

Comment: Since Docker on Mac runs inherently on a VM (and we unfortunately don't know the IP of the VM) we cannot really expose ports the traditional way.

Comment: I suspect if any firewall is  trying to block the access on main host, like we do have this issue in Linux systems

Comment: Also I was checking https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds. See if you have similar issues here